# Como Puedo Obtener El Index De Un Elemento Con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo obtener el index de un elemento cuando haga click en el.

```
<p>Parrafo 1</p>
<p>Parrafo 2</p>
<p>Parrafo 3</p>
<p>Parrafo 4</p>
<p>Parrafo 5</p>

var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
{
  p[i].addEventListener('click', funcion_uno);
}

funcion_uno()
{
  console.log('el index del elemento clickeado es: '...);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: A que index te refieres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en tu ejemplo, obtenes todos los elementos con tag `p` y le asignas una funcion `onclick` con el index:

```
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach((element, index) => {
    element.onclick = () => alert(index)
});
```